# Uploader: How to set custom folder name equal to user id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, carrierwave

I have implemented a CarrierWave uploader, and would like the folder path to include the id of the organization it belongs to.

In the organizations controller:

```
def create
  @organization = Organization.new(new_params)
  if @organization.save
    Image.upload_file(@organization.id)
  end
end
```

So the controller method passes the organization's id to a model method. The model method in the Image model is as follows:

```
def self.upload_file(id)
  newimage = Image.new
  File.open('app/assets/emptyfile.xml') do |f|
    newimage.file_name = f    
  end
  newimage.organization_id = id
  newimage.save!
end
```

In the Image uploader I specify the folder path:

```
def store_dir
  "#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

My question: In this folder path I would like to include the id of the organization (the one passed on as parameter to the model method) instead of `model.id` (which will be the id of the record in the Image model instead of the id of the record in the Organization model). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it with the `model.organization_id`?

```
def store_dir
  "#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.organization_id}"
end
```